# Convert base64 string into hex

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

How can I convert the bytes of a base64 string to the hex representation of them using AMPScript?

Answer (score 1):

Convert the base64 to string and that string to hex

[Base 64](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/utilities_ampscript_functions/base64decode/)

[String tohex](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/utilities_ampscript_functions/stringtohex/)

Comment: It doesn't give the results I expect. Base64Decode returns something like this. 
V????????????x. It looks like byte[] to me

Comment: What was the second parameter did you tried UTF-8/ UTF-16 if you have the raw base64 value try to convert online with another tool to see if it is a valid one. What is using during encoding?